# define defaults for plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, default

I want define defaults for my plugin, this is javascript code:

```
var opts = {
    'width': 957,
    'height': 590,
    'left': ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.width),
    'top': ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.height)
};​
```

but `opts.left` return `NaN`.
what is problem?

**EDIT:** I want use *width* from my object in my object.

Comment: You need to tell us more on where this opts is inside. If you have this inside plugin code and you are calling this like a jQuery function.. then `$(this).width()` should get you the width

Comment: @Vega Let me explain, I have a plugin, I want set the width, height, left and right by default, so I created an object and on this object I have 4 property (width, height, left, right). the width and height is a constant (width: 957 and height: 590) now I want calculate the left and top value from this properties , so I need the value of this property in my object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.width` isn't a numeric value.

> **Origin of NaN values**
>
> NaN values are generated when arithmetic operations result in undefined or unrepresentable values. Such values do not necessarily represent overflow conditions. A NaN also results from attempted coercion to numeric values of non-numeric values for which no primitive numeric value is available.

---

**Update based on the comment:**

`this` isn't the object, it the caller of the function. so `this.width` won't give you the `width` of the property.

[**Working LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F5YXW/)

Comment: thank you but how I can use a property from my object in my object ?

Comment: @MajAfy. You should define it as an object with a constructor.

Comment: thanks, that was useful, I wrote this code : http://jsfiddle.net/WmEZK/ but is this logical? I want use this for defaults of my plugin

Comment: @MajAfy. You included `mooTools` instead of `jQuery`... [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmEZK/1/)

Comment: yes you right I changed to jQuery, but I mean was can I use this code for defaults of my plugin ? how can I change the left property from out side of my plugin ? like : `$('div#anyID').myPlugin({width: 400});`

Comment: @MajAfy. Just give it the instance of the new object.

Comment: would you please help me how can I do  this ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `this.width` is returning you <s>`undefined`</s> an non-numeric value.

**For ex:** `100 - undefined` will return you `NaN`

Try using `$(this).width()` and `$(this).height()`,

```
var opts= {
      'width': 957,
      'height': 590,
      'left': ($(window).width()/2)-($(this).width()),
      'top':  ($(window).height()/2)-($(this).height())
};
```

The above should work provided `this` in valid context.

Comment: I trying use $(this) instead of this but both of them return the element, I want use the width in opts

Comment: @MajAfy `$(this).width()` and not just `$(this)`. Also are you calling opts from `this` context.

Comment: yes I know, I mean I replaced this with $(this) so this.width changed to $(this).width, but return NaN again, if I wrote $(this).width() will return the width of my element, but I need the value of width property in my object.

Comment: @MajAfy What do you mean by value of width property... `$(this).width()` will return the value of the width which is an number http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Me5ZV/1/

Comment: Let me explain, I have a plugin, I want set the width, height, left and right by default, so I created an object and on this object I have 4 property (width, height, left, right). the width and height is a constant (width: 957 and height: 590) now I want calculate the left and top value from this properties , so I need the value of this property in my object.